# Run Script via Android app and prevent process being killed

Tags: android

I have a script that is run from within an android app via:

```
Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

outputStream.writeBytes("sh /system/bin/androidtolinux.sh"+ "\n");
outputStream.flush();

outputStream.writeBytes ("\n\nexit\n");
outputStream.flush();

su.waitFor();
```

This works fine however part of the script stops zygote via:

```
setprop ctl.stop media & setprop ctl.stop zygote
```

After this the app is killed along with all processes it spawns including the process running the script.

SO my question is how can I run my script via an app but so that the scripts process is not killed once `setprop ctl.stop media & setprop ctl.stop zygote` is run.